# Display an enlarged version of the number 9 using assembly language

Tags: assembly

I am very new to assembly language and feel a little bit out of my depth

I do not expect anyone to go about writing the code for me here but what I am trying to figure out are the steps to take to display this pattern.

Enlarged number Bit pattern Hex number

```
 $$$          01110         0E
$   $         10001         11
$   $         10001         11 
 $$$$         01111         0F 
    $         00001         01
    $         00001         01
$$$$$         11111         1F
```

> Define a bit pattern for each number and use this pattern to display the individual lines:
>
> For the ‘9’ displayed above you should define a string of 7 hex numbers, one hex number for each line.
>
> To display the first line, step through the bit pattern, displaying a space if the bit is equal to zero and displaying a ‘$’ otherwise. Write a carriage return and line feed to the screen and move to the pattern for the next line. Display all 7 lines of the enlarged number.

If I define this as the bit pattern in my program:

```
v1: 0Eh,11h,11h,0Fh,01h,01h,01h,1F
```

Would I need to convert the hex into binary? I just need some guidance as to how to handle stepping through the bit pattern. How do I step through this bit pattern without converting v1 to binary?

Thanks

Comment: Everything is binary in the computer. And bit shifting is what you want

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @Rumbles No. I am picking up assignments and doing these to get a better understanding of the language. I just needed some advice as to how to go about tackling this. I'm looking into bit shifting now.

Comment: Think about how you'd do it in C, or whatever other language of your choice.  Or really, just figure out the steps you want the computer to take, before getting bogged down in actual asm instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well so far I have written down how I want to do this. for each bit pattern shift each bit to the left if the bit = 1 then display '$' else if the bit = 0 display ' '. After each bit pattern though I would want to move to a new line. The code is very different to c++ so I'm going to keep working it.

Comment: @Karma88: your final result is just bytes in memory, with a newline (`'\n'`) after every line (which you can call `write(2)` or `fwrite(3)` on, or you can write them one char at a time).  In C (or C++), that's just an array of `char`.  If you're not to thinking about C in terms of how it could compile, or what's actually happening to data in memory, then that's something you'll have to learn at the same time as assembly language.

Comment: Which environment have you picked up? An OS? Dos? Bios? None?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I am working in NASM, Windows.